# SQL Server 2012 Weird Rounding with ROUND

Tags: sql-server, floating-point

Here is the example :

```
DECLARE @V1 FLOAT
SET @V1 = 0.05
DECLARE @V2 FLOAT
SET @V2 = 1.00
DECLARE @V3 FLOAT
SET @V3 = 102.90
SELECT @V1*@V2*@V3
SELECT ROUND(@V1*@V2*@V3, 2)
```

Result 5.145

Result 5.15

```
DECLARE @V1 FLOAT
SET @V1 = 0.05
DECLARE @V2 FLOAT
SET @V2 = 10.00
DECLARE @V3 FLOAT
SET @V3 = 10.29
SELECT ROUND(@V1*@V2*@V3, 2)
```

Result 5.145

Result 5.14

Comment: Floating point numbers are not exact.  You can get variation in the lowest order digits.  So, 5.144000000001 rounds one way, 5.143999999997 rounds the other way.

Comment: The calculation of 0.05 * 1.00 * 102.90 and 0.05 * 10.00 * 10.29 should be the same ?

Comment: FLOAT is an approximate value. That is the answer. It's not the same because it's not exact.

Comment: Stop using FLOAT and ROUND. Use DECIMAL(10,2) and then convert the product to this same definition and the "problem" should go away.